Ambiguous question about conditional probability when drawing a card from a deck
A card is drawn from a standard deck. Find the probability that it is a diamond given that it is a red card.
I think I've done my due diligence in thinking about this problem as shown in the comments below from a social media exchange.
My best conclusion so far is "at random from a standard deck" and "given that it's red" are basically mutually exclusive, so the solution is undefined.
(Put another way, if it is given that the card is red, then it is not drawn at random from a standard 52 card deck.)
I'm curious to hear what the brightest minds have to say about this, bearing in mind that the Monty Hall Problem had some very experienced and skilled mathematicians having to eat their hats, so to speak.
Discussion
Me:
What's the sequence here? You draw a card from a standard deck. You don't look at it, but someone else does. If it's red by a 50% chance, they tell you this. Now if you gamble, there's a 50% chance you'll win.
But, there is a whole extra step here where 50% of the time you don't play, because the other person says the card you picked was black.
I don't think you can ignore this extra step and jump straight to a 50% overall chance.
I suspect the wording of the question obscures the subtlety here.
Put another way, we are looking at the combined probability of 2 separate events. First 50% for black vs red, then 50% for diamonds vs hearts. By the formula for multiple events (the AND rule), we have 50% x 50%, giving 25%. This aligns with the probability of getting a diamond when simply drawing a card at random from a standard 52 card deck.

Person X:
You do not understand the wording; that is the problem. In probability and statistics, terms like “given that” or “conditioned on” are sample space restrictors. In this problem the question becomes “in the sample space of single draws that result in a red card, what is the probability it is a diamond? Clearly 1/2, and it is called a conditional probability, the condition being that the draw results in a red card. Questions about how you would conduct the related experiment might be interesting, but they do not influence the probabilistic conclusion.
Conditional probability is an important tool in solving a wide variety of problems.

Me:
I disagree. There is formal mathematical language and there is informal language. Even without that caveat, you appear to be describing a situation where initial picks of a black card have been discarded, giving the condition "we know it's red" only a 50% chance of occurring.
BTW I seem to recall that there is a major divide on the interpretation of conditional probability in the mathematical community - I think possibly relating to the "fence" demonstrated by this problem. Do that ring a bell?
Put another way, if you are discussing a restricted sample space, surely you have to account for the probability of that restriction occurring, no?

I don't understand your reasoning.  Conditional probability has a definition which is easily applied in this context, and the answer is $\frac 12$.

I think on closer examination, it is clear that the question doesn't make sense. If you disagree, please explain the sequence of events represented by the question.

I see no ambiguity at all in the question. It is clearly asking for the the conditional probability that the card is a diamond given that it is red.  You appear puzzled that gaining new information about a situation enables you to re-estimate various probabilities, but why?  Doctors, say, routinely re-estimate probabilities that their patient has this or that condition based on the results of examinations and tests.  Same phenomenon.

If you see no ambiguity, then you should presumably be able to describe a real world situation where the conditions given in the question actually occur. I invite you to do so. I also refer you to my comment on the answer below, about perspectives.

You draw a card from the deck, and hand it to me.  I look at it and tell you that it is red.

I can't follow your thoughts on perspectives.  Obviously people with different bits of knowledge estimate probabilities differently.  So what?

If you look at the only answer so far to this question, the perspective issue is mentioned - "Then, for you (but not for me!) the probability that it is a Diamond is 1/2". The case where you tell me the card is red only occurs 50% of the time. It is not possible that I draw a card at random from a 52 card deck but that it is guaranteed that it is red. There must be a sequence of events - the observation that the card is red must occur after the initial draw. In that case, the situation has changed to a 1/2 probability, but that does not represent the original act of drawing from a 52 card deck

You asked me for a "real world" model of the problem and I gave you one.  I agree that the observation that the card is red must have come after the card was selected but can't imagine what meaning that might have.  I think we are going in circles here.

"I think we are going in circles here." That is exactly my  point. The question is inherently flawed. I've just updated my last comment to try to make this clearer. I'm confident there is a serious issue here, that has not been addressed in comments and answers so far.

But you haven't given any clue as to what you think the serious issue is.  Anyway, I don't think my comments are helping so I'll stop writing them.  Good luck.

I have explained in precise detail what I think the serious issue is, multiple times on this post. I invite you to ponder further.

There is nothing mysterious going on here. Suppose I draw a card at random, without showing it to you. You ask me "What colour is it?" I say "Red." Then, for you (but not for me!) the probability that it is a Diamond is $\frac12$.

But surely the perspective should not change the mathematical probability? And if it does, shouldn't that perspective be explicitly mentioned for the question to be unambiguously meaningful?

Probability always depends on the perspective! If I don't show you my card, the probability that it is the Ace of Spades is $1/52$ for you, but $0$ or $1$ for me. Again, nothing mysterious here.

So the potential for opposing interpretations doesn't bother you? I think this problem has analogous features, and there seems to be ambiguity about the timing of knowledge availability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_girl_paradox

Also, if perspectives affect the outcome, then surely the perspective must be provided in the question? For example in this question, what is the probability of a diamond from the perspective of someone who knows the card is red vs someone who doesn't? I don't think this information is implicit in the question here, so I still think the answer is undefined.

Is the perspective not explicit? We, the reader, are the only perspective mentioned or asked about. There's no second perspective that knows more or less than we do.

I also do not think that this is analogous to the Boy/Girl paradox. That paradox arises from the fact that learning information strictly about a group, and not about any individuals specifically, can lead to differing probabilities than learning about a specific individual and that it's very easy to misinterpret knowledge about one as knowledge about the other. In this problem knowledge about the group and knowledge about the individual are the same, since our group size is only 1, just the card we drew.

"We, the reader, are the only perspective mentioned or asked about." I can think of 3 perspectives. 1 - the reader, who doesn't know which "internal" perspective is taken. 2 - The perspective of the "knower" of the fact that the card chosen is red (an omniscient god, or a person who tells you so), and 3 - the player, who has simply picked a card at random from a 52 card deck. I'm still pretty convinced that there is insufficient information to determine the answer unambiguously. Or rather, that the question is inherently self-contradictory. Let's ignore the boy/girl paradox analogy for now.

I will be honest, thinking this problem could have you considering perspectives 2 or 3 seems like a large stretch (assuming #3 doesn't know that the card is red. If they do then 1 and 3 are identical.) It feels on par with declaring (5+5) ambiguous because we haven't explicitly declared which base we are working in. Nevertheless, the problem is still answerable, you just have to do it three times and be explicit yourself.
